# Find where is exactly an element with swift

Tags: ios, position, cgrect

I want to dynamically generate textfields under my static textfield.

Let's say that I have my textfield in that position:
x: 50 y: 374 width: 220 height: 30

I used that code to see what it will return:

```
print(mytextfield.center.y) // 500
print(mytextfield.frame.origin.y) // 0.0
```

(I use swift 3)

Both wrong.

Any Ideas where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most probably you're talking about different coordinate systems. Where did you get this frame: (x: 50 y: 374 width: 220 height: 30)?

Comment: @alexburtnik from storyboard.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your view hierarchy to the question? Just open the storyboard, press cmd+shift+4 and select your view hierarchy.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: There isn't enough information to know what is going wrong. If you have a textfield with that frame, you should see `389.0` and `374.0` in the console. Seems as though your textfield is moving - perhaps it has constraints?

Comment: yes it has but these positions are from storyboard with iphone 5 dimensions and the console logs are from running on simulator iphone 5

Comment: It is probably better to add constraints programatically to your new text fields rather than relying on the frame of the existing text fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are printing from `viewDidLoad`, at this point of time the view haven't layout yet, you need to print this at `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubview` then you can get correct frame

Comment: I tested both, viewDidLayoutSubview worked! thank you

Comment: @mikevorisis if you are using them to adding subview then just create and add the subview in `viewDidLoad`, then change it's frame in the others function, take care that `viewDidLayoutSubview ` will call multiple times so dont create anything there

Comment: I noticed that and I did this 
if flag1 == 0 {
        ypos = mytextfield.frame.origin.y
        flag1 = 1
        }